# colorbox displays text after excessive wait

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I have a page with a hidden div in a colorbox that I show on a link click. The colorbox works perfectly, but it takes about 8 seconds to show. I am not making any back-end queries and I'm only displaying existing (hidden) text and changing styles. I have the colorbox instantiated with open: true and that seems to have no effect. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.colorbox').colorbox({
      width: '50%', 
      open: true, 
      left: '2%'
    });

    jQuery('.colorbox').bind('cbox_complete', function() {
      jQuery('#colorbox').addClass("colorbox_opened");
    });

    jQuery('.colorbox').bind('cbox_closed', function() {
      jQuery('#colorbox').removeClass("colorbox_opened");
    });

    jQuery('#cboxClose').bind('cbox_load', function() {
      jQuery('#cboxClose').hide();
    });

    jQuery('#cboxClose').bind('cbox_complete', function() {
      jQuery('#cboxClose').show();
    });

  });

</script>
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="colorbox" class="colorbox_opened" style="display: block; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-right: 0px; top: 0px; left: 33px; position: absolute; width: 818px; height: 239px;">
  <div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 269px; width: 818px;">
    <div>
      <div id="cboxTopLeft" style="float: left;"></div>
      <div id="cboxTopCenter" style="float: left; width: 818px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxTopRight" style="float: left;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;">
      <div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 239px;"></div>
      <div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 818px; height: 239px;">
      <div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="display: block; width: 818px; overflow: auto; height: 239px;">
        <h1>FAQ</h1>
        <div id="faq_show">
          <h3>Question</h3>
          <div class="question"> My question text </div>
          <h3>Answer</h3>
          <div class="answer"> My answer text </div>
          <div>
            <a href="/setup/faqs/11/edit">Edit</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
      <div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
      <div id="cboxTitle" style="float: left; display: block;"></div>
      <div id="cboxCurrent" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
      <div id="cboxNext" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
      <div id="cboxPrevious" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
      <div id="cboxSlideshow" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
      <div id="cboxClose" style="float: left;">close</div>
    </div>
    <div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left; height: 239px;"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check the colorbox examples here: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

When you have a look in the source code you'll notice that all callbacks are inserted right in the colorbox init like that:

```
$(".callbacks").colorbox({
                onOpen:function(){
                     alert('onOpen: colorbox is about to open');
                     },
                onLoad:function(){
                     alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the 
                     targeted content'); },
                onComplete:function(){
                     alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed
                     the loaded content'); },
                onCleanup:function(){
                     alert('onCleanup: colorbox has begun the close process'); },
                onClosed:function(){
                     alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely
               closed');
               }
});
```

I guess it's easier when you just take that as example and just adjust the functions to meet your requirements.